# Let $A$ any matrix so $A^H A$ is Hermitian and $A^H A $ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

*Question:*
Let $A$ any matrix so $A^H A$ is Hermitian and $A^H A $ is positive definite.

*Answer:*
The first part is easy as: $A^H A =A A^H \Rightarrow AA^H = (A^HA)^H=(AA^H)^H$.
But how to prove (quickly) $<u|AA^H|u> \geq 0$?

Comment: $\langle u, A^HAu\rangle = \langle Au, Au\rangle$

Comment: @Surb thk for your answer. What do you do to prove that $<u|A^HA(u)>=<A(u)|A(u)>$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of $A^H$ ?

Comment: $A^HA$ is not necessarily positive definite. It may be positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u^{H}A^{H}Au$ = $(Au)^{H}(Au)=||Au||^{2}$